# how to navigate and select multiple files using only keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I would like to select multiple files non sequentially as in the illustration below...

[image]

On [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows) I could simply hold down the `Ctrl` Key, navigate with `Up` and `Down` keys and hit the `Space` key to select or deselect a file.

But on mac if I hold down the `Command` key and hit `Down` arrow, it opens up the file (tested on images).
and `ctrl + down` arrow does something weird with the windows..

Is there any way to select such thing without mouse (which is way slower of course..)?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Windows MacOSX is not well designed for keyboard only access. There is no built in method for doing this. Sorry you're stuck with using the mouse in these situations.